# How to play video in full screen in Apple TV (TvOS)

Tags: swift, tvos, avkit

in IOS apps, AVKit provides AVPictureInPictureController, which provides many features like full screen, play, pause. i want to implement same in TVOS, but there is no such class in AVKit.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `AVPlayerViewController` instead
or you can use `AVPlayer` and a `UIViewController` like `iOS`